# How to search and update values in a list of dictionaries using pymongo for a mongo entry?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have mongo entry like this

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fdc78778adbdedd17ce6ff3"),
    "solution_id" : "5fd6e275a675f2000134b243",
    "versions" : [
        {
            "local" : 2,
            "s3" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to search and update the value of `"s3"` key to **"abc"**. How to do that using pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a "route" to the specific key to be able to set it. You can use the dot notation to determine the element in the object structure that needs to be updated; in your case this is `versions.0.s3`. If you're happy to do this in python, and tweaking your code, it would look like:

```
for i in cursor1:
    for index, j in enumerate(i.get('versions', [])):
        if j.get('local') == 2:
            db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': i.get('_id')}, {'$set': {f'versions.{index}.s3': 'abc'}})
```

You can do the whole thing in a single update operation using the `$` [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). NB This only updates the first match on `local == 2` found; the python example would update all matching items in the array.

```
db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(document_id), 'versions.local': 2}, {'$set': {'versions.$.s3': 'abc'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

```py
item_id = ObjectId("5fdc78778adbdedd17ce6ff3")

db.collection.update({'_id': item_id}, {'$set': {'versions.$.s3': 'abc'}})
```

#### Option 2

```py
query = {}
item_id = ObjectId("5fdc78778adbdedd17ce6ff3")
items = db.collection.find({'_id': item_id})

for i, _ in enumerate(items):
    query[f'versions.{i}.s3'] = 'abc'

db.collection.update({'_id': item_id}, {'$set': query})
```